# Error occurred prerendering page "/". API fetch failed Next js app router

Tags: next.js

page.tsx

```
const Home =() =>{
  return(
  <div className=" ">
    
   
    <div className="flex flex-col h-full my-20 space-y-8">
      <div className="mx-5 rounded-md   h-96 relative">
     
      <ResizablePage/> 
    </div>
    <div className=" min-h-screen md:px-10 sm:px-5">
     <Featured/>  

    </div>
    
   
   </div>
    
  </div>
  )
}
export default Home;
```

feature component
the get data is giving an error my guess is that it is trying to fetch the data from the api routes and those routes are not served during the building process but how to solve this ?

```
import { productSchema } from "@/types/types";
import Image from "next/image";
import React from "react";
import { z } from "zod";
import { Button } from "./ui/button";
import { Card, CardTitle, CardContent, CardFooter } from "./ui/card";


const getData = async () => {
  const baseURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL || 'http://localhost:3000';
  const apiURL = `${baseURL}/api/products`;
  
  const res = await fetch(apiURL, {
    cache: "no-store",
  });

  

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed!");
  }

  const data = await res.json();

  // Validate the array of products
  const validatedProducts = productArraySchema.parse(data);

  return validatedProducts;
};

const productArraySchema = z.array(productSchema);
type ProductArrayType = z.infer<typeof productArraySchema>;

const Featured = async () => {


  
const featuredProducts: ProductArrayType = await getData();



  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-6 gap-4 mx-auto p-4 max-h-screen overflow-y-scroll">
      {/* Card 1 */}
      {featuredProducts.map((item:any, index:any) => (
      <Card key={index} className="p-1 flex flex-col  space-y-1 bg-gradient-to-br from-emerald-500 ">
        <CardTitle className=" flex justify-center p-3" >
          <p>{item.title}</p>
        </CardTitle>

        <CardContent className=" relative h-40">
          <Image
            src={item.img}
            fill
            sizes="(max-width: 600px) 100vw, (max-width: 600px) 50vw, 33vw"
            alt="my pic"
            className="rounded-sm adbolute inset-0"
          />
          </CardContent>

<CardFooter className="flex flex-col items-center space-y-1 justify-center">
<p className="text-sm "> {item.desc}</p>
          <p className=" text-md font-semibold"><span className="px-2">price:</span>{item.price}</p>

          <Button variant={"default"}>Add to cart</Button>
        </CardFooter>
       
        
        
         
        
      </Card>
      ))}
```

In development it is working fine, but during deployment on vercel the get data gives an error gives error like this

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
Error: Failed!
    at getData (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:1:10868)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Featured (/vercel/path0/.next/server/app/page.js:1:10972)
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by adding fallback and as  I was using the prisma I added the `"postinstall": "prisma generate"` and  `"build": "prisma generate && next build", in the script.`

Answer (score -1):

It seems like during the prerendering process, your application is failing to fetch data from your API endpoint. This could be due to several reasons, including:

**API Endpoint Unavailable:**
The API endpoint might not be accessible during the build or prerendering process.

**Incorrect API URL:**
Ensure that the API URL is correctly defined and points to the right endpoint, especially in different environments like production and development.

**CORS Policy:**
If your API is hosted on a different domain, you might encounter Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) issues.

To troubleshoot this issue:

**Check API Endpoint Availability:**
Make sure that your API endpoint is accessible and returns data when accessed directly from a browser or using tools like Postman.

**Verify API URL:**
Double-check the API URL in your code, including any environment variables used to define it.

**CORS Configuration:**
If your API is hosted on a different domain, ensure that it allows requests from the domain where your Next.js app is hosted. You might need to configure CORS headers on your server.

Additionally, you can consider:

**Using Static Site Generation (SSG):**
If the data from the API is static or can be precomputed at build time, you can use Next.js's Static Site Generation (SSG) to fetch and prerender the data during the build process.

**Fallback:**
Implement a fallback mechanism in your code to handle cases where fetching data during prerendering fails. You can show a loading indicator or an error message to users in such cases.

By addressing these points, you should be able to diagnose and resolve the issue with fetching data during prerendering in your Next.js app deployed on Vercel.

Comment: Answers created by generative AI (eg ChatGPT) are banned on StackOverflow. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned for more details